# how to get a grand child from parent in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all i need a help i need to display a grand child from parent id that means one id=2 has a child id=3 and child id=3 has a child  id=4 (here child id=3 is parent id for child id=4).

below is my tables:

```
table object_data:
obj_id | type | title 
---    |------|------
3217   |crs   |it 
3221   |grp   |xyz 
3228   |tst   |test 

table object_reference:
ref_id | obj_id 
---    |---------
337    |3217       
338    |3221      
343    |3228 

table tree:
tree | child | parent 
---  |-------|------
1    |338    |337 
2    |343    |338
```

from above three tables i need to display like id 3217 has id 3228 i need a query .i am able to write a query for only child id not for grand child .any one help to sort out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the parent and grand child info:

```
SELECT
    a.`type` as `parent_type`,
    a.`title` as `parent_title`,
    g.`type` as `gchild_type`,
    g.`title` as `gchild_title`
FROM `object_data` a
JOIN `object_reference` b
    ON a.`obj_id` = b.`obj_id`
JOIN `tree` c
    ON b.`ref_id` = c.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` d
    ON c.`child` = d.`ref_id`
JOIN `tree` e
    ON d.`ref_id` = e.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` f
    ON e.`child` = f.`ref_id`
JOIN `object_data` g
    ON f.`obj_id` = g.`obj_id`
```

**EDIT**

This gives you the parent, child and grand child info:

```
SELECT
    a.`type` as `parent_type`,
    a.`title` as `parent_title`,
    g1.`type` as `child_type`,
    g1.`title` as `child_title`,
    g.`type` as `gchild_type`,
    g.`title` as `gchild_title`
FROM `object_data` a
JOIN `object_reference` b
    ON a.`obj_id` = b.`obj_id`
JOIN `tree` c
    ON b.`ref_id` = c.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` d
    ON c.`child` = d.`ref_id`
JOIN `object_data` g1
    ON d.`obj_id` = g1.`obj_id`
JOIN `tree` e
    ON d.`ref_id` = e.`parent`
JOIN `object_reference` f
    ON e.`child` = f.`ref_id`
JOIN `object_data` g
    ON f.`obj_id` = g.`obj_id`
```

Comment: thank you soo much for helping me with your knowledge .its working fine on database phpmyadmin..now i will try to write in php script if i get any error i will contact you bro

Comment: hi sir i need to display child tiitle as well.can you help me? please

Answer (score 0):

You can easily join the three tables by matching the right columns to each other:

```
SELECT tree.child
FROM object_data
JOIN object_reference ON object_data.obj_id = object_reference.obj_id
JOIN tree ON tree.parent = object_reference.ref_id
WHERE object_data.obj_id = 3217
```

Comment: with this query am not getting grand child am getting only 338 child id.i need to get child id 343

Comment: Then replace the last line with `WHERE object_data.obj_id = 3221`. Whatever object ID you specify from `object_data`, you'll get the relevant child from `tree`.

Comment: But 343 is not 3217's grandchild. 343 is 338's child and 338 is 3221's child, so when you look up 3221 you get 343. When you look up 3217 you get 338.